# Django Window Function FirstValue Producing Invalid SQL

Tags: django, sqlite, django-orm, window-functions

I'm trying to use a window function to get the first of each group and its producing the sql query below - I took the sql and played around with it in the console and it appears that the CAST() function is causing the issue. Is there a way to get rid of this in the query?

Django 2,1 Code:

```
def contract_list(user):

    price_window = Window(
        expression=FirstValue('settle_price'),
        partition_by=F('contract'),
        order_by=F('trade_time').desc()
    )

    market_prices = Trade.objects.filter(
        contract__isnull=False
    ).annotate(
        market_price=price_window
    ).values(
        con=F('contract'),
        market_price=F('market_price'),
    ).order_by(
        'contract'
    ).all()
```

produces this SQL run on a SQLite3 database:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(FIRST_VALUE("trading_trade"."settle_price") AS NUMERIC) OVER PARTITION BY "trading_trade"."contract_id" ORDER BY "trading_trade"."trade_time" DESC) AS "market_price", 
    "trading_trade"."contract_id" AS "con" 
FROM 
    "trading_trade" 
WHERE 
    "trading_trade"."contract_id" IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY 
    "trading_trade"."contract_id" ASC
```

Again, the issue seems to be related to the `CAST(FIRST_VALUE("trading_trade"."settle_price") AS NUMERIC)` since removing the cast function produces a result set.